# Filtering the Visual Studio toolbox

Tags: visual-studio, filtering, add-in, delphi-xe, toolbox

Does anyone know if it is possible at all to filter the Toolbox's items in Visual Studio using an add-in?

Visual Studio 2010 introduced the ability to search but I want to filter, for example: type in button and it must show all items containing "button", same as on this on this Delphi XE screenshot:

[image: Delphi XE Tool Palette filtering] [image: Visual Studio Toolbox]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily Visual Studio 2012 now has that feature!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a very good answer for this question. I copied from the VS blog:

**In VS 2010 Beta2, we’ve added the ability to search for controls in the toolbox by name.  To use it, put focus in the toolbox (by clicking in it, for example) and start typing the name of the control you want to find.  As you type, the selection will move to the next item that matches what you've typed so far.**

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2009/10/26/toolbox-search.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is something not possible as microsoft does not reveal the secret of adding toolbox controls details completely. They make change the process for each platform and for each versions of visual studio. if we have a clear details of how they add, we can also do the similar kind of small application with search capability and add it as add-in.